# How can I get my Login Screen to appear on my primary monitor?

Tags: greeter

Currently my login screen is on my secondary smaller moniter(VGA) and I would like it to appear on my main monitor (DVI) anyway to do this at all? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. You can track it [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1628711) by adding yourself where it says "Does this bug affect you?" and "subscribed to this bug's notifications". I recommend subscribing so that developers prioritize the issue and can ask for your logs, if needed.